# Using characteristic polynomial for getting an asymptotic information to a recurrence relation with non-constant coefficient

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, roots, characteristic-polynomial

Let's define the following two recurrence relations with $c_{1,2} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The constant coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ are the same for both recurrence relations.

**First recurrence relation (constant coefficients)**

$a_0(x) = 1$

$a_1(x) = c_1 x$

$a_n(x) = c_1 x a_{n-1}(x) + c_2 x a_{n-2}(x)$ with $c_{1,2} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$

**Second recurrence relation (variable coefficients)**

$b_0(x) = 1$

$b_1(x) = \frac{c_1}{2} x$

$n b_n(x) = c_1 x b_{n-1}(x) + c_2 x b_{n-2}(x)$

**Target of investigation**

The regions of $x$ where the polynomial $b_n(x) \neq 0$.

**Preparatory work**

In [this question (StackExchange - Mathematics)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3562032/681678) I showed that $a_n(x) \neq 0$ if the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial $\Delta_{\lambda} > 0$. Because these polynomials have only positive coefficients, all real roots lie on the negative real axis.

$\Delta_{\lambda} = x \left( c_1^2 x + 4 c_2 \right) > 0$

So $a_n(x) \neq 0$ if $x < -\frac{4 c_2}{c_1^2}$ (or $x > 0$).

Motivated from this result, I investigated into the polynomial $b_n(x)$ and got numerical evidance that $b_n(x) \neq 0$ if $x < -\frac{4 c_2}{c_1^2}n$.

**Question:** Is it mathematical correct if I prove this (asymptotic) behavior by the following connection with the result from $a_n(x)$ ? Otherwise: can someone show me another (better, simpler) way to prove it?

$n b_n(x) = c_1 x b_{n-1}(x) + c_2 x b_{n-2}(x)$

$b_n(x) = c_1 \frac{x}{n} b_{n-1}(x) + c_2 \frac{x}{n} b_{n-2}(x) = c_1 y b_{n-1}(x) + c_2 y b_{n-2}(x)$ with $y = \frac{x}{n}$.

So from the previous results, I know that $a_n(x) \begin{cases}> 0 & \text{ if } n \text{ is even} \\ < 0 & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}\end{cases}$ and $x < -\frac{4 c_2}{c_1^2}$.

The relation $b_n(x)$ is similar to $a_n(x)$ such that every $x$ in $a_n(x)$ gets replaced by $\frac{x}{n}$ in $b_n(x)$. So the most reduction of $x$ would happen if I set $n$ in the recurrence relation to the current value of $n$.

For example, I take a new recurrence relation instead of $b_5(x)$ I use:

$b_0^{(*)}(x) = 1$

$b_1^{(*)}(x) = \frac{c_1}{5} x$

$b_n^{(*)}(x) = c_1 \frac{x}{5} b_{n-1}^{(*)}(x) + c_2 \frac{x}{5} b_{n-2}^{(*)}(x)$

I then can use again the results from the investigation for constant coefficients which $b_n^{(*)}(x) \neq 0$ if $\frac{x}{5} < -\frac{4 c_2}{c_1^2}$.

And for every $b_n(x)$ I would define a new recurrence relation such that at the end I am able to say that:

$b_n(x) \neq 0$ if $\frac{x}{n} < -\frac{4 c_2}{c_1^2}$ or respectively $x < -\frac{4 c_2}{c_1^2} n$